# ls with numeric range doesn't work inside bash script

Tags: bash, ls

I have a folder with files named as `file_1.ext...file_90.ext`. I can list a range of them with the following command:

```
$ ls /home/rasoul/myfolder/file_{6..19}.ext
```

but when I want to use this command inside a bash script, it doesn't work. Here is a minimal example:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$1
st=$2
ed=$3

FILES=`ls ${DIR}/file\_\{$st..$ed\}.ext`
for f in $FILES; do
  echo $f
done
```

running it as,

```
$ bash test_script.sh /home/rasoul/myfolder 6 19
```

outputs the following error message:

```
ls: cannot access /home/rasoul/myfolder/file_{6..19}.ext: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace expansion happens before variable expansion.

(Moreover, don't parse *ls* output.). You could instead say:

```
for f in $(seq $st $ed); do 
    echo "${DIR}/file_${f}.ext";
done
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked after removing braces around `f` in `echo` command.

Comment: What shell are you using? It should work with or without the braces.

Comment: I use standard terminal in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You're always allowed to put braces around variable names. They're not needed in this command, but should still work.

Comment: Something is broken in your shell if you can't use braces and my `eval` solution didn't work.

Comment: @Bamar: Are you using Mac shell? If so, it might explain why we get different results.

Comment: This lists the file names whether the files exist or not.

Answer (score 2):

`BASH` always does `brace expansion` before `variable expansion` which is why `ls` is looking for a file `/home/rasoul/myfolder/file_{6..19}.ext`.

I personally use `seq` when I need to expand a number range that has variables in it.  You could also use `eval` with `echo` to accomplish the same thing:

```
eval echo {$st..$ed}
```

But even if you used `seq` in your script, `ls` would not iterate over your range without a loop.  If you want to check if files in the range exist, I would also avoid using `ls` here as you will get errors for every file in the range that doesn't exist.  `BASH` can check if a file exists using `-e`.

Here is a loop that would check if a file exists within the range between variables `$st` and `$ed` and print it if it does:

```
for n in $(seq $st $ed); do 
    f="${DIR}/file_$n.ext"
    if [ -e $f ]; then
        echo $f
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The range pattern `{A..B}` does not accept variables for `A` or `B`. You need constants for them.
A workaround might be to start a subshell like this:

```
RESULT=$(bash -c "ls {$a..$b}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Barmar suggested a workaround, using `eval`. Also you can start a subshell with `bash -c`. Added example

Answer (score 1):

Numeric ranges have to be literal numbers, you can't put variables in there. To do it you need to use `eval`:

```
FILES=`eval "ls ${DIR}/file_{$st..$ed}.ext"`
```

Here's a transcript of my test (I tried it in bash 4.1.5 and 3.2.48).

```
imac:testdir $ touch file_{1..30}.ext
imac:testdir $ st=6
imac:testdir $ ed=20
imac:testdir $ DIR=.
imac:testdir $ FILES=`eval "ls ${DIR}/file_{$st..$ed}.ext"`
imac:testdir $ echo "$FILES"
./file_10.ext
./file_11.ext
./file_12.ext
./file_13.ext
./file_14.ext
./file_15.ext
./file_16.ext
./file_17.ext
./file_18.ext
./file_19.ext
./file_20.ext
./file_6.ext
./file_7.ext
./file_8.ext
./file_9.ext
imac:testdir $
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it also outputs the same error!