# How can I list a range of files in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, ls

I've got several files in a folder, with the following names:

```
FILE_201.txt
FILE_206.txt
FILE_215.txt
FILE_223.txt
FILE_229.txt
FILE_232.txt
```

I want to select files between two values (e.g. between "210" and "230").
From the command line, running

```
ls -1 FILE_{210..230}.txt
```

lists the desired files; no problem. However, if I run the following Bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -1 FILE_{$1..$2}.txt
```

passing `210` and `230` as arguments to it, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't about running the command at the command line or from a script. You can check that for yourself, by running the following at the command line:

```sh
$ set 210 230 # assigns variables $1 and $2 the values "210" and "230", resp.
$ ls -1 FILE_{$1..$2}.txt
ls: FILE_{210..230}.txt: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, you get the same error as the one raised by your script file. The problem is that **brace expansion happens *before* variable expansion**.

In this case, by the time, `$1` and `$2` get expanded to `210` and `230`, it's too late for the range to be interpreted as such; the `{ .. }` part simply sticks around, without any special meaning attached to it.

Anyway, using `ls` here is a bad idea, because you're going to get an error for each filename in the range that doesn't match an existing file. You'd be better off using a combination of a for loop and `seq`, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20831575/2541573):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# test.sh

for n in $(seq $1 $2); do 
    f="FILE_$n.txt"
    if [ -e $f ]; then
        printf $s\\n "$f"
    fi
done
```

Example:

```sh
$ touch FILE_209.txt
$ touch FILE_213.txt
$ touch FILE_224.txt
$ touch FILE_232.txt
$ bash test.sh 210 230
FILE_213.txt
FILE_224.txt
```

Comment: Your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/q/29007821/1983854 was perfectly good, only that the other one helped me better. Please consider undeleting it, since it adds value to the whole question!

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks, but I realised one problem with it: if, for some reason, you want to check out all the files from a commit *other than the current one*, `git reset --hard <commit>` will reset your current branch to `<commit>`, whereas poke's `git checkout -- .` will not.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, you need to "eval" your line. i.e.

```
eval "ls FILE_{$1..$2}.txt
```